# Adding rows to a datagridview from a dataset not bound to the datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview (DGV) that contains 3 rows.  I want to add the results (4 rows) of a MySQL query to the DGV. The result of the query is placed in a DataSet (DS).  What is the syntax for ADDing the four DS rows to the DGV?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the rows from your dataset by looping.

```
Dim myConnObj As New MySqlConnection
Dim myDataSet As New DataSet
Dim myDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand

myCommand = New MySqlCommand("Your Query", "Your Connection")
myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "list")

With myDataSet
   For i as integer = 0 to .Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
       DataGridView1.Rows.Add(.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString(), .Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString())

'.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, etc...) the number of column you add should match the column count of your DataGridView

   Next
End With
```